# Why does "Func<bool> test = value ? F: F" not compile?

Tags: c#

I have seen similar questions to this, but they involve different types so I think this is a new question.

Consider the following code:

```
public void Test(bool value)
{
    // The following line provokes a compiler error:
    // "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is 
    // no implicit conversion between 'method group' and 'method group".

    Func<bool> test = value ? F : F;
}

public bool F()
{
    return false;
}
```

Now, according to the C# 3.0 Standard,

> The second and third operands of the
>   ?: operator control the type of the
>   conditional expression. Let X and Y be
>   the types of the second and third
>   operands. Then,
>
> If X and Y are the same type, then
>   this is the type of the conditional
>   Otherwise, if an implicit conversion
>   (§6.1) exists from X to Y, but not
>   from Y to X, then Y is the type of the
>   conditional expression. Otherwise, if
>   an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists
>   from Y to X, but not from X to Y, then
>   X is the type of the conditional
>   expression. Otherwise, no expression
>   type can be determined, and a
>   compile-time error occurs.

It seems to me that in my sample code, X and Y must be of the same type, since they are the selfsame entity, *Func*. So why does it not compile?

Comment: i dont know, but can you explain how can u write a method name with void return type like this in an expression `Func`??

Comment: Sorry, in my effort to simplify the code from my original code, I erroneously removed the return type. I've fixed it now!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question was changed significantly, so my original answer is a bit off by now.

However, the problem is essentially the same. I.e. there could be any number of matching delegate declarations for `F` and since there is no implicit conversion between two identical delegate declarations the type of `F` cannot be converted to `Func<bool>`.

Likewise, if you declare

```
private delegate void X();
private delegate void Y();
private static void Foo() {}
```

You cannot do

```
X x = Foo;
Y y = x;
```

---

Original answer:

It doesn't work because method groups cannot be assigned to an implicitly typed variable.

`var test = Func;` doesn't work either.

The reason being that there could be any number of delegate types for `Func`. E.g. `Func` matches both of these declarations (in addition to `Action`)

```
private delegate void X();
private delegate void Y();
```

To use implicitly typed variables with method groups, you need to remove the ambiguity by casting.

---

See [archil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6015814/199364) for a *concrete* example of one way to fix this. That is, he shows what the corrected code might look like [assuming the delegate you desire to match is `Action`].

Comment: But even if you specify type of test variable explicitly as: public delegate void FuncDelegate(); This line still will not be working: 
FuncDelegate funcDelegate = value ? Func : Func;
Why?

Comment: I've fixed up my sample to match what I had in my original code; I oversimplified it when I posted it here the first time.

Comment: I changed my code so that I am no longer assigning to an implicitly typed variable.

Comment: Thanks Brian - I think my problem was in thinking that methods intrinsically had types - but only delegates do.

Comment: @BashirMagomedov - it appears that compiler does not look outside the conditional expression, in deciding whether the desired signature can be determined.

Answer (score 8):

```
var test = value ? (Action)Func: (Action)Func;
```

Actually, `type` of method is expressed by delegate it matches. `System.Action` that i used to cast methods to, is the delegate with signature returning void and taking no parameters - it matches your `Func()` method. And now your `test` will know that it is type of System.Action. Delegates are something like interfaces for methods. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Interesting, but why do `value ? (Action)f : g;` and `value ? f : (Action)g;` both compile?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq - Because when you give the needed *signature* `(Action)` to either half, the compiler knows what the desired goal is. It then can determine whether the other half can be cast to the same signature.