# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined (Func)

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

When assigning a method to a `Func`-type, I get the compilation error `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'method group' and 'method group'`.

This only happens with the `? :` operator. The code:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public static string One(int value)
    {
        value += 1;
        return value.ToString();
    }
    public static string Two(int value)
    {
        value += 2;
        return value.ToString();
    }
    public void Testing(bool which)
    {
        // This works
        Func<int, string> actionWorks;
        if (which) actionWorks = One; else actionWorks = Two;

        // Compilation error on the part "One : Two"
        Func<int, string> action = which ? One : Two;
    }
}
```

I found [some information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx) about co- and contravariance, but I don't see how that applies to the situation above. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6015747/why-does-funcbool-test-value-f-f-not-compile

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to explicitly provide the signature of at least one method group. However, after doing it the compiler will allow you to declare `action` as an implicitly-typed local:

```
var action = which ? (Func<int, string>)One : Two;
```

The reason this happens is that the return type of `operator ?:` is not deduced based on what you are trying to assign it to, but based on the types of the two expressions. If the types are the same or there is an implicit conversion between them, the compiler deduces the return type successfully; otherwise, it complains that there is no conversion.

Comment: That's the thing. The types are exactly the same (or is in c# the type of the One method different from the Two method, because it are two different methods?).

Comment: @doekman: The type of `One` and `Two` is "method group" -- there may be multiple overloads, and the compiler does not attempt to narrow them down to "reasonable" choices just because they appear as the operands of `?:`.

Comment: OK, that's what "method group" means. I think I get a picture now of the error. Thanks all.

Answer (score 6):

When you directly assign a function to a delegate, the compiler will convert the function to the required delegate type if it matches the signature.

However, when you're using the ?: operator, as far as the compiler is concerned you're not directly assigning to a delegate, so it doesn't know what type to use for One and Two, and so it thinks the two types used in the ?: operator don't match.

The only fix is making the conversion explicit:

```
Func<int, string> action = which ? new Func<int, string>(One) : new Func<int, string>(Two);
```

Answer (score 3):

Jon's solution works

```
var action = which ? (Func<int, string>)One : Two;
```

Another alternative is to create a new anonymous delegate yourself. This is semantically lil' different but I think this can be useful too.

```
Func<int, string> action = x => which ? One(x) : Two(x);
```

I find this lil' more elegant, though not as short..

Comment: Your answer is more elegant but the `if`result will be decided on every call to the `action` while on the @Sven answer the if result will be decided only once.

Comment: @AkiraYamamoto you're right. Though in this case it's just a variable check and mostly wont be a performance issue, its elegance is affected by the logical inefficiency/meaninglessness.