# Pass base constructor a different value based on a condition within the constructor

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

I have a constructor as follows

```
public class Person : Animal
{
    public Person(Settings settings) : base(settings.ActionProperty1)
    {

    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public Animal(Action a)
    {

    }
}

public class Settings
    {
        public bool Flag { get; set; }

        public Action ActionProperty1 { get; set; }

        public Action ActionProperty2 { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I pass the base constructor a different value based on some condition. i.e. Something like the following.

```
public Person(Settings settings) : base(settings.flag ? settings.ActionProperty1 : settings.ActionProperty2)
{

}
```

The above gives me a compilation error: CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'method group' and 'method group'

Also, i can't resolve this by adding a property setter in the base class. I need to do this in the constructor call to the base

Edit: The answer was provided in the second duplicate linked here. [Type of conditional expression cannot be determined (Func)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308328/type-of-conditional-expression-cannot-be-determined-func) I had to cast one of the optional parameters to an Action. Thank you

Comment: @DavidG They are of type Action

Comment: @dymanoid updated original

Comment: Works for me (after changing `settings.flag` to `settings.Flag`)